# Uploading files to S3 bucket - Python Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to put a string (which is an xml response) into a file and then upload it to a amazon s3 bucket. Following is my function in Python3

```
def excess_data(user, resume):
    res_data = BytesIO(bytes(resume, "UTF-8"))
    file_name = 'name_of_file/{}_resume.xml'.format(user.id)
    s3 = S3Storage(bucket="Name of bucket", endpoint='s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com')
    response = s3.save(file_name, res_data)
    url = s3.url(file_name)
    print(url)
    print(response)
    return get_bytes_from_url(url)
```

However, when I run this script I keep getting the error - `AttributeError: Unable to determine the file's size.` Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using [s3boto](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) (requires python-boto) in my Django projects to connect with S3.

Using boto is easy to do what you want to do:

```
>>> from boto.s3.key import Key
>>> k = Key(bucket)
>>> k.key = 'foobar'
>>> k.set_contents_from_string('This is a test of S3')
```

See this [documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html) the section Storing Data.

I hope that it helps with your problem.